# Ubuntu 16.04 randomly crashes under high cpu load

Tags: crash

Since about one week my LapTop on Ubuntu 16.04 crashes at random moments when under high cpu load. That is either during Audio Conversion via TAudioConverter / Wine or Chess Analysis with Stockfish or Komodo in SCIDvsPC, so it is not program-specific.

It immidiately shuts down without any sign of warning.

Where can I find a log file to post, so as to give you more information?

```
gratis@Aurora:~$ lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 222,6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  15,9G  0 part [SWAP]

gratis@Aurora:~$ df

Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8153360         0   8153360   0% /dev
tmpfs            1634696      9688   1625008   1% /run
/dev/sda1      229572820 204352820  13535292  94% /
tmpfs            8173468     87072   8086396   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8173468         0   8173468   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1634696       104   1634592   1% /run/user/1000

gratis@Aurora:~$ free

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16346940     3572364     5575488      753016     7199088    11623860
Swap:      16690172           0    16690172

gratis@Aurora:~$ grep -i sensor /var/log/syslog*

gratis@Aurora:~$
```

Comment: Give us the results from the terminal app, of `df` and `free`.

Comment: Is your CPU overheating?

Comment: I don't think so. I can run stable for hours performing either of the tasks mentioned above (even on surfaces that don't transport heat well) and sometimes it just crashes after a few minutes.
@heynnema: Could you please elaborate on exactly what i should do. I google the terms "ubuntu crash df" and "ubuntu crash free", but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Start the `terminal` app from the Unity dashboard, and type `lsblk` and `df` and `free` and `grep -i sensor /var/log/syslog*` (4 separate commands), and then **copy** all of the output to the clipboard, then **edit** your question here, and **paste** the output into your question (put `<pre>` in front of the beginning of the pasted text, and `</pre>` at the end). Also, do you run your laptop on battery, or AC power?

Comment: If I remember correctly the last crashes happened while it was charging, but I haven't removed the battery if I understand correctly.

Comment: remember to start comments with @heynnema if you want to assure that I see them. See my answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have possibly two different problems here.

## First:

It appears that you're out of disk space. Some of the programs that you're running may generate huge data files. Open the `Disk Usage Analyzer` from the Unity dashboard and try to figure out where your disk space has gone.

You may need to re-partition your hard drive to obtain more working space. If you edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, we can explore that if we need to.

## Second:

We can't tell if overheating is an issue for you, until we install tools to monitor this.

Open the `terminal` app from the Unity dash and type the following commands, one at a time:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`
- `sudo apt-get install sensord`
- `sudo apt-get install sensors-applet`
- `sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors`

Then calibrate the hardware sensors by typing:

- `man sensors-detect` # to read the man pages
- `sudo sensors-detect`
- `sensors -f` # to see it in action

Then start `Hardware Sensors Indicator` from the Unity dashboard, and set the preferences to auto-start at login, and to default to Fahrenheit. Monitor this indicator in your top panel and watch that the temperature stays around 120-150 degrees. More and you've possibly got a problem.

Comment: the indicator-sensors repo isn't properly maintained anymore, but simply using the "sensors" revealed the cpu temp peaks at about 82°C (which is about 30 higher than your 150°F limit), but right next to the value it says: (84°C high, +100°C critical).

It is true that I am low on disk space, but it just crashed with about 15GB free space. Still I know that for audio conversion large .wav files are temporarily created and it could be the chess engine doesn't exclusively use ram. I would think though the program would rather report an error than the whole OS crash...

Comment: Indicator-sensors is in his `trusty` dist (deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexmurray/indicator-sensors/ubuntu trusty main), and he's made code changes as recent as July 2015. You can download source at https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors and https://github.com/alexmurray/indicator-sensors. You can also install `psensor` as a substitute. 180 degrees hot, and your fans should be running, yes? You might also look at installing `thermald`. Its .conf file should work for most computers, but you may need to adjust it for yours. Mine is set for 140-145 degrees max.

Comment: If you've got Intel processors, make sure that `intel-microcode` is installed. This will make sure that the processors are up to the latest revision. After installation and reboot, in terminal, you can type `dmesg|grep microcode` to see its operation in updating the processors.

Comment: I did as you said and the output for dmesg|grep microcode was:

[    0.000000] microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.080703] microcode: CPU2 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.088470] microcode: CPU4 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    0.096284] microcode: CPU6 microcode updated early to revision 0x1e, date = 2015-08-13
[    4.268992] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e

Comment: [    4.269013] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e
[ 4.269061] microcode: CPU2 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e [ 4.269084] microcode: CPU3 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e [ 4.269128] microcode: CPU4 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e [ 4.269151] microcode: CPU5 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e [ 4.269196] microcode: CPU6 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e

Comment: [ 4.269221] microcode: CPU7 sig=0x306c3, pf=0x20, revision=0x1e [ 4.269336] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba

Comment: Good. Lets see if the microcode updates help at all. Are you going to try and install psensor and/or indicator-sensors? How are your fans doing when you're at high temp?

Comment: I installed psensor and now have that start with the system. Unfortunately neither adding the indicator-sensors ppa nor compiling it from source worked for me, but I guess it doesn't matter now. It is looking for some config file.

I tried running thermald: "sudo thermald", but it just goes to the next line starting with user@...:~$. It does not report any error.

If I just go "thermald" it says: You must be root to run thermald!

Comment: Hum, as I recall, the prefs file had to be created manually. Just create an empty file and start indicator-sensors. Thermald is a process (`ps auxc|grep thermald`)that runs, not an app you run directly. However, if you stop the process, you can run `thermald -d` and watch it in real time. Check out `man thermald` and man `thermal-conf.xml`.

Comment: thanks! But it turns out, that wasn't the problem. Maybe also the program is running properly and I'm just misinterpreting the terminal output.

gratis@Aurora:~$ indicator-sensors

[main] ERROR: Failed to open icon cache dir /home/gratis/.cache/indicator-sensors/icons

[aticonfig] DEBUG: Checking for hybrid system with integrated GPU active

[aticonfig] WARNING: Error calling aticonfig to detect if running on a hybrid system with integrated GPU active: Failed to execute child

Comment: process "aticonfig" (No such file or directory)

[dbus-plugin] DEBUG: Acquired a message bus connection

[dbus-plugin] DEBUG: Acquired the name com.github.alexmurray.IndicatorSensors

Comment: Are you running indicator-sensors from the terminal, or from the Unity dashboard. It should be the dashboard. Search for "hardware" to find it. Also, please start new comments with `@heynnema` if you want me to see the comment. It'll flag me that way.

Comment: ok, thanks. If I start it from the dashboard its icon it will blink in the applications bar on the left for a couple seconds and then disappear. This always happens when a program fails to load. When I try to run it via the terminal I get the output mentioned above.

Are there any config presets I can download for thermald? If yes, which would you recommend?

Comment: What you do is kill the thermald process, then run `sudo thermald -d` to watch it in real time. That'll give you the info you need to modify a thermal-conf.xml. The default file may work for you, or require only a few mods. If you do the man page I suggested earlier, you'll also see some examples.